# Time, and if statement

Tags: php

I'm attempting to check if a time is past the given time on the locked account. I have attempted several ways and the problem is consistent. Any help is appreciated. The format of the sql entry is the same as $datetime in the variable, except the datetime in the database is set to +30 minutes from the time it was locked. The problem is that it is ALWAYS returning the variable as 1, unless it's flipped to say $datetime >= $row['locked'] then it always returns 0. What I want to happen is if the time is within thirty minutes it returns 1, if not then 0.

First

```
function anotherMethod($userclean)
{
if($this->isLocked($userclean) == 1)
    {
        header('Location: login.php?i=l');
        die();
    }
}
```

Second

```
    function isLocked($userclean)
{
$datetime = date('m-d-Y h:i:s');
$results = mysqli_query($this->con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$userclean."'");
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) 
    {
        $str = $row['locked'];     
        }
    if ($datetime >= $row['locked']){
        $islocked = 1;
    }else{
        $islocked = 0;
    }
    return $islocked;
}
```

Comment: If you want to compare date-time strings, *always* use the international standard format: `Y-m-d H:i:s`.

Comment: Will do. Is this for readability purposes or is there another issue?

Comment: Well put it this way. Which is bigger, `02-06-1992` or `01-01-2016`? Clearly the 2016 date should be bigger, but compare them in that format and "Feburary" is bigger.

Comment: Ah, I see where that may bring about future issues. Thank you for that. Unfortunately, as you probably knew, the problem still exists. But you did prevent future problems.